# Where to store MySQL credentials in PHP scripts?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, security, webserver

I know I need to store my login information outside of my web root in case Apache is cracked, but I am unsure of what my 'web root' is, where to store my login information, and how to access them from PHP.

Could someone explain?

Comment: Related: [Storing passwords for MYSQL in PHP application in a secure manner](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23367665/53114)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your web root, which is `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in PHP, is the folder on your filesystem that your webserver (in this case, Apache) points to for a particular host.

For example, if you put this code in your index.php file and visit your domain name (or subdomain name), it will tell you your web root.

```
    <?php
    header("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
    die($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
    ?>
```

It should say something like, `/home/some_user/public_html` or `/var/www`. In this case, you want to create a path that is not inside of this directory.

For example: `/home/some_user/config` or `/var/webconfig`.

You do ***NOT*** want to store it in `/home/some_user/public_html/config` (notice the public_html) or `/var/www/webconfig` (notice this is a subfolder of `/var/www`)

The idea of storing data outside your web root is that an attacker cannot navigate to `http://yoursite.com/config/mysql.txt` and obtain your passwords. LFI and directory traversal attacks are not in the scope of this initiative.

**You also should not check any sensitive information (database credentials, encryption keys, etc.) into version control.** Ever.

#### How to access them from PHP?

That depends how your configuration is encoded.

```
<?php
$config = parse_ini_file('/home/some_user/config/mysql.ini');
// OR
$config = json_decode('/home/some_user/config/mysql.json');
// OR
require_once '/home/some_user/config/mysql_config.php';
?>
```

Comment: In Apache `httpd` parlance, it's your `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: I tend to reconfigure Apache so that `/var/www/default` is the standard catch-all vhost, and then all projects on the server follow the form `/var/www/project/web/`. Thus project-specific config can go in `/var/www/project/config/`.

Comment: That's exactly what I do, only it's `/var/www/project/public` so I can easily remind myself that anything there is readable. Also, it makes `public/static/*` filename jokes possible.

Comment: Better make your database server only accessible from localhost. Then it doesn’t matter if the credentials get leaked as they are worthless outside the server.

Comment: Then I can access variables in my included file easily by just calling them? Ex. $dbname ?

Comment: Additionally, require_once and include are not working for me, why is this?

Comment: Check the path. If you're looking for `/var/webconfig/` but your files are in `/home/some_user/config/` it won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, I use a folder outside my webroot for application code (functions, etc..) including the mysql connecting php. I create a folder (/home/user/application or similar) and make a mysqlconnect.php file there with the code to connect to mysql or error out. Then, make sure that the path (/home/user/application/ is in the include directory, and at the top of index.php(index.html), include:

```
<?php
include '/home/user/application/mysqlconnect.php';
```

It is also good advise to store any password obfuscation code in this way, so that your method, dynamic salt, and static salt can not be compromised in a similar way.

Comment: It's also handy to name these `.inc` instead and flat-out reject serving `*.inc` in your server rules.