# want to remove hostname,username and pasword from php code

Tags: php, mysql, json

i am having php code like below

```
<?php
/*  $host='127.0.0.1';
$uname='root';
$pwd='password';
$db="android";
*/  
require_once('dbConnect.php');

/*  $con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");
*/   
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$approval=$_REQUEST['approval'];

$flag['code']=0;

$sql = "UPDATE ap_events SET event_approval = '$approval' WHERE id ='$id'";

if($r=mysqli_query($sql,$con))
{
    $flag['code']=1;
}

print(json_encode($flag));
// mysql_close($con);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

but i want to remove the hostname username and password details from the above code, for the same i have another dbConnect.php code below:

```
<?php
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','password');
define('DB','android');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
```

producing results always code = 0 means unsuccessful. and when i remove the comments it is successful!!

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to store MySQL credentials in PHP scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24787953/where-to-store-mysql-credentials-in-php-scripts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed

```
$approval=$_REQUEST['approval'];
```

and

```
if($r=mysqli_query($sql,$con))
```

i changed to

```
if($r=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
```