# Is it a bad idea to store sensitive data as a protected/private property in a PHP class?

Tags: php, class, security

I know private properties can only be accessed by the class itself and protected properties can be accessed by the class and classes that extend it. Let's say I have a class like this:

```
class Example {

    protected $sensitive;

    public function __construct($data) {

        $this->sensitive = $data;

    }

 }
```

When using `var_dump` all the properties are listed in the dump, I know properties can be hidden using `__debugInfo` like so:

```
public function __debugInfo() {

    $result = get_object_vars($this);

    unset($result['sensitive'];

    return $result;

}
```

But I was just wondering if it's bad practice to store data like this? I'll give an example of what one of my situations is:

I have a config file that stores various database login credentials for different databases.

A Database class is instantiated and added to a Container when the App class is instantiated. Then a method within the Database class is called in a connections file which adds all these database connection details to a protected property within the Database class ready for use later on when we want to connect to a database "on the fly".

Obviously this protected property in the Database class stores every potential login details to all the databases all in one place and that is what worries me, I'm probably worrying about nothing, but it would be nice to have that piece of mind knowing if this is bad or not.

To me the only way an end-user could see this data was if I was to accidentally leave a `var_dump` somewhere on a live site for them to see?

Comment: To my knowledge, it's okay to store the credentials as a property, the only way someone can read them is if he can access the files, if he can do so he'll just read the credentials from any file.

Comment: That’s what I was hoping to hear, thanks!

Comment: Just store the config file (where the credentials are) outside your web root so it is not accessible to the public. (in case something goes wrong and your server starts dumping PHP code). Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24787953/where-to-store-mysql-credentials-in-php-scripts

Comment: I think you've mostly answered your own question here. Storing a sensitive variable in the class *definition* is dangerous if anyone is likely to ever have access to the source code. Storing it within an object *at runtime* is dangerous if and only if you accidentally leave a `var_dump`/etc call in your code. Theoretically, if someone had access to your runtime then they could extract a variable from a currently executing script, but if that's the case then you've probably got bigger problems.

Comment: @Mehdi Yeah the config .env file where the actual hard coded credentials are stored are outside of the public directory already so I'm covered there.

Comment: @iainn That's what I was thinking, just nice to know I wasn't missing anything just in case. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you're hard-coding secrets, that's a problem, so please don't do that.

If you're loading them from a configuration file at runtime and aiming to prevent them from being leaked by `var_dump()`, no, that's not a bad idea. That's what the [HiddenString](https://github.com/paragonie/hidden-string) library does. (In fact, feel free to just use that, if you'd like to minimize your own in-house technical debt.)