# Storing DB Credentials

Tags: php, sql, database, security

I want to make secure connection to my database, hence I've tried to locate a file outside `public_html`, but for some reason (which I guess depends on my host) I cannot do it.
I've thought about creataing a `credentials.php` file, and adding the following .htaccess rule:

```
<files credentials.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

And then importing `credentails.php` is needed. I would like to know if using `include("credentials.php")` in a file **which is not protected** by .htaccess won't reveal the credentials. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Apply *defense in depth*, then it basically doesn’t matter.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23370881/53114)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, php-code isn't visible for the client. Php is executed server-side and then sent to the client. (Surf to any php site and check the source code). The only way to get a php-file is to download it (but i'm not sure how one would do that).

So I think you are fine doing what you do :)
(if I'm wrong please correct me, This is what i've always learned, and it would be great to know if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you print or send the credentials through GET, they won't be visible to anyone outside the server, so you don't even need to use .htaccess.